# Apache tomcat port issues in java

Tags: tomcat

[image]

I tried different ports while installing tomcat, and again reinstall tomcat and eclipse, but why every port number gave me this issues (mentioned in image)?

I use tomcat 8.0.28 version.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Tomcat it can be configured as system daemon, so it can be started alone.

Then when configuring Tomcat inside Eclipse it can be launched twice so then you will get port collision. Ensure you have disabled Tomcat as system daemon (at least stop it) and then let Eclipse be the only one who can manage Tomcat.

Comment: How to disable tomcat as a system daemon?

Comment: Well it depends on your operating system. It seems you are using a recent version of MS Windows. I googled and found this [tutorial to manage system services](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/12411-services-start-stop-disable-windows-8-a.html). You have to find the service called Tomcat.

Comment: hi malaguna,as you told me , I did the same, now my tomcat is started in eclipse, but when I run any program with server, it gives me 404 error why?

Comment: So your question has been answered and solved, and now you have another one. HTTP 404 means that the server can not found the resource you asked for, maybe you have an error in your app and thus the app is not being deployed. Please, ask another question and facilitate related info.